# How do I play a Winsound beep while code is running?

Tags: python, python-3.x, winsound

I'm making a sorting algorithm visualizer with Tkinter, but whenever I try to make a "Beep" sound, it stops the program until the sound is finished.

Here's a "paraphrasing" of my code:

```
import winsound

def visualiser(array):
    for i in array:
        check_conditions(i,other_item)
        winsound.Beep(height,100)
   check_if_sorted(array)
```

but whenever it "Beeps", it stops the program until the beep is finished. How do I stop this?

Comment: I believe the `PlaySound()` method has an async option if that would help.

Comment: If `Beep()` *didn't* stop the program, then all of the beeps in your loop would happen at the same time - that seems unlikely to be of any use.  The simplest fix I can think of would be to run this loop in a separate thread, so it doesn't block Tkinter's mainloop.  (Unfortunately `PlaySound()` only supports asynchronous playback from files, not from memory, so you'd have to actually write each separate beep tone to disk to use it.)